# System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object Object name: 'SslStream'

Tags: c#, websocket

I'm trying to implement a **WebSocket** client using c# native client (was using WebSocket4sharp before) and I'm fighting against an exception about disposed **SslStream**. I've been searching for many hours of forums/github/stackoveflow but can't find a solution.

Implementation:

```
    class NativeWebSocket
    {
        private ClientWebSocket m_Client = new ClientWebSocket();

        public event Action OnOpen;
        public event Action<WebSocketState, string> OnClose;
        public event Action<WebSocketState, string, Exception> OnError;
        public event Action<string> OnMessage;

        public bool IsConnected => m_Client.State == WebSocketState.Open;
        public WebSocketState State => m_Client?.State ?? WebSocketState.None;

        public void ConnectAsync(string p_URL)
        {
            m_Client.ConnectAsync(new Uri(p_URL), CancellationToken.None).ContinueWith((p_Result) =>
            {
                if (    p_Result == null
                    ||  p_Result.IsCanceled
                    ||  p_Result.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion
                    ||  m_Client.State != WebSocketState.Open)
                {
                    OnError?.Invoke(m_Client.State, m_Client.CloseStatusDescription, p_Result.Exception);
                    return;
                }
                Logger.Instance.Error($"ConnectAsync {m_Client.State}");

                StartListenerTask();
                Task.Delay(3000).Wait();
                OnOpen?.Invoke();
            });
        }
        private void InitializeClient()
        {
            m_Client?.Abort();
            m_Client = new ClientWebSocket();
        }

        public void Send(string message)
        {
            try
            {
                m_Client.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message)), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
                Logger.Instance.Error("Send>" + message);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Instance.Error("send ended " + m_Client.State + " " + m_Client.CloseStatusDescription);
                Logger.Instance.Error(ex);
            }
        }
        private async void StartListenerTask()
        {
            try
            {
                var message = "";

                while (IsConnected)
                {
                    WebSocketReceiveResult result;
                    var buffer = new byte[1024];

                    try
                    {
                        result = await m_Client.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
                    }
                    catch (System.Exception ex)
                    {
                        Logger.Instance.Error(ex);
                        Logger.Instance.Error("task ex " + m_Client.State + " " + m_Client.CloseStatusDescription);
                        break;
                    }

                    if (result == null)
                        continue;

                    switch (result.MessageType)
                    {
                        case WebSocketMessageType.Close:
                            Logger.Instance.Error("manual close > " + result.CloseStatus + " " + result.CloseStatusDescription);
                            Close();
                            break;
                        case WebSocketMessageType.Text when !result.EndOfMessage:
                            message += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer).TrimEnd('\0');
                            continue;
                        case WebSocketMessageType.Text:
                            message += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer).TrimEnd('\0');
                            OnMessage?.Invoke(message);
                            break;
                        case WebSocketMessageType.Binary:
                            break;
                        default:
                            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
                    }

                    Logger.Instance.Error("Receive>" + message);
                    message = "";
                }

                Logger.Instance.Error("task ended " + m_Client.State + " " + m_Client.CloseStatusDescription);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Instance.Error(ex);
            }
        }

        internal Task Close()
        {
            return m_Client.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "", CancellationToken.None);
        }
    }
```

Logs

```
Connecting to wss://irc-ws.chat.twitch.tv:443
ConnectAsync Open
Connection to wss://irc-ws.chat.twitch.tv:443 opened successfully!
Twitch connection opened
Trying to login!
Send>PASS oauth:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Send>NICK hardcpptv
Send>CAP REQ twitch.tv/membership
Send>CAP REQ twitch.tv/commands
Send>CAP REQ twitch.tv/tags
System.OperationCanceledException: Aborted ---> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'SslStream'.
  at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckDisposed () [0x00008] in <ef151b6abb5d474cb2c1cb8906a8b5a4>:0 
  at System.Net.Security.SslStream.get_Impl () [0x00000] in <ef151b6abb5d474cb2c1cb8906a8b5a4>:0 
  at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndRead (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <ef151b6abb5d474cb2c1cb8906a8b5a4>:0 
  at System.IO.Stream+<>c.<BeginEndReadAsync>b__43_1 (System.IO.Stream stream, System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1+FromAsyncTrimPromise`1[TResult,TInstance].Complete (TInstance thisRef, System.Func`3[T1,T2,TResult] endMethod, System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x00000] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  ...
task ex Aborted 
task ended Aborted
```

Maybe I'm doing something wrong about tasks, or maybe it's a mono bug? this piece of code run under mono/unity.

Comment: Which line of code is causing the error?

Comment: await m_Client.ReceiveAsync(

Comment: Check `m_Client`; make sure it's not disposed when you call `ReceiveAsync`.